# Canvas, Animación de imagen

Tags: reactjs, canvas, img

Estoy trabajando en react y Sass, y he decidido hacer unas animaciones con colisiones y Canvas. Consigo hacer animaciones con con cuadrado o un círculo, y al meterle una imagen con `ctx.drawImage(imagen,x,y)` me sale la imagen perfectamente pero no la animación.

Os dejo el código para que os hagáis una idea.

> No he puesto todo el código por que son muchas cosas, como el cálculo de las colisiones, las objetos que interactúan, la física ambiental...

Pienso que la duda que tengo se puede observar con el código que facilito, es añadir la image que importo desde la carpeta assets/img llamada *Captus* y que sea el player. Actualmente consigo que aparezca pero no interactuar con ella, sí puedo con el cuadrado que se crea.

```js
 //animation frames
        (function () {
            var requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame;
            window.requestAnimationFrame = requestAnimationFrame;
        })();
        
        var canvas,
            image,
            ctx,
            width,
            status,
            height,
            player;


function reset() {

            canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
            ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            image = new Image();
            image.src = Captus;
            
            
            width = 800;
            status = 'playing';
            height = 600;
            player = {
                image,
                color: '#B9DAFB',
                x: 0,
                y: height / 2,
                width: 30,
                height: 30,
                speed: 6,
                velX: 0,
                velY: 0,
                jumping: false,
                grounded: false,
                facing: 'right',
                shot: false
            };
              keys = [];
              
                    canvas.width = width;
            canvas.height = height;

        }
        
         reset();
        
         function update() {
            // verificar la entrada del jugador
            if (keys[38] || keys[87]) {
                // flecha arriba
                if (!player.jumping && player.grounded) {
                    player.jumping = true;
                    player.grounded = false;
                    player.velY = -player.speed * 2;
                }
            }
            if (keys[39] || keys[68]) {
                // flecha derecha
                player.facing = "right";
                if (player.velX < player.speed) {
                    player.velX++;
                }
            }
            if (keys[37] || keys[65]) {
                // flecha izquierda
                if (player.velX > -player.speed) {
                    player.velX--;
                }
                player.facing = "left";
            }
            if (keys[32]) {
                // espacio
                if (status === 'win') {
                    reset();
                } else if (player.shot === false) {
                    player.shot = true;
                    bullet.direction = player.facing;
                    bullet.x = player.x + 30;
                    bullet.y = player.y + 10;
                }

            }
            
             //dibujar jugador
            ctx.fillStyle = player.color;
            
            ctx.drawImage(image,10,10)
          
            ctx.fillRect(player.x, player.y, player.width, player.height);
             requestAnimationFrame(update);
             }
             
             
              document.body.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
            keys[e.keyCode] = true;
        });

        document.body.addEventListener("keyup", function (e) {
            keys[e.keyCode] = false;
        });

        update();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

Vale he encontrado una solución mirando y leyendo documentación, no se si es la correcta pero por ahora funciona a falta de retocar una serie de parámetros pero.... funciona, a ver este era el código cuando dibujaba al player pero he visto que si modifico el ctx.drawImage puedo hacer lo que quería

```js
//dibujar jugador
            ctx.fillStyle = player.color;
            
            ctx.drawImage(image,10,10)
          
            ctx.fillRect(player.x, player.y, player.width, player.height);
             requestAnimationFrame(update);
             }
```

Código modificado con la corrección, cambiando los parámetros dentro del ctx.drawImage(img,x,y)

```js
 ctx.drawImage(image,player.x,player.y)
```

le paso los valores de X e Y del player y listo ahora tengo que modificar parámetros para que ocupe justo lo que necesito